# Can't debug worker role (emulator)

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, xdebug, azure-worker-roles

I have created worker role in `VisualStudio 2015` `AZURE SDK 2.9`, `C#`

i added breakpoints to start of the each method:

```
    public override void Run()
    {

    public override bool OnStart()
    {

    private async Task RunAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
```

but when i start my application in debug mode none of these breakpoints hits. In emulator i see this messages:

> [fabric] Role Instance: deployment29(49).Channels.Jobs.Integr.Sync.Jobs.0
>
> [fabric] Role state Started
>
> [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart():Integr.Sync.Jobs.DistributedJobRole
>
> [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Integr.Sync.Jobs.DistributedJobRole
>
> [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run():Integr.Sync.Jobs.DistributedJobRole

what I'm doing wrong? how to stop worker role on breakpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After small investigation i found the root of the problem:

after changing role class from:

```
public class IntegrationsSyncRole: RoleEntryPoint
```

to

```
public class IntegrationsSyncRole: DistributedJobRole
...
public class DistributedJobRole: RoleEntryPoint
```

breakpoints stopped hitting.

Solution was to remove intermediate class and inherit `IntegrationsSyncRole` from `RoleEntryPoint` without any other classes.